# I am trying to use pdfmake libraries in Angular5 and it is giving ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfkit/index.d.ts:603:23 - error TS1110: Type expected

Tags: node.js, angular, pdfmake, vfs

I tried using following import statement :

`import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'; import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'; (pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;`

```
It gave follwoing errors :
 Failed to compile. 
ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfkit/index.d.ts:603:23 - error TS1110: Type expected.

ERROR in node_modules/@types/pdfkit/index.d.ts(603,23): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
node_modules/@types/pdfkit/index.d.ts(603,33): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
node_modules/@types/pdfmake/interfaces.d.ts(868,13): error TS2456: Type alias 'Content' circularly references itself.
node_modules/@types/pdfmake/interfaces.d.ts(924,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
```

Comment: Did you try updating your typescript to latest version?